# Certain programs freezing until resizing the window

Tags: chrome, graphics, freeze, intel-graphics

I've got a bit of a problem with running certain programs.

When I run a Chromium (without any flags set) it opens, but will freeze on the new tab screen. If I click or type or interact in anyway, there are no visual changes, until I resize the window, which will trigger a single update, and then proceed to freeze on that frame again.

When I launch Chromium from the terminal (again, no flags) it opens like before, and gives me this error:

```
InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

When I use the  `--disable-gpu`  flag, all my issues are resolved and I can use Chromium like normal, apart from anything that uses WebGL, leading me to think it's perhaps an issue with my graphics card? To further back this up, when I launch Minecraft (the actual game, not the launcher) I have the exact same problem. The loading Mojang screen is frozen, until I resize the window, which it will update itself again.

I have a Lenovo S730 with an Intel i7-10510U, with integrated graphics. I am running Manjaro, and the output of  `uname -a`  is  `Linux finch 5.5.8-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 5 20:29:51 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux` . Output of `inxi -Fxxxz`:

```
System:
  Host: finch Kernel: 5.5.8-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.2.1 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.34.4 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM 3.34.1 Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 81U4 v: Lenovo Yoga S730-13IML 
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 v: Lenovo Yoga S730-13IML 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40709 WIN serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: LENOVO v: BRCN16WW date: 08/14/2019 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 16.1 Wh condition: 42.7/42.0 Wh (102%) volts: 15.0/15.4 
  model: CPT-COS L17C4PE1 type: Li-poly serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
  cycles: 43 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-10510U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Kaby Lake rev: C L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 36812 
  Speed: 1102 MHz min/max: 400/4900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1176 2: 1200 
  3: 1171 4: 1200 5: 1200 6: 1200 7: 1199 8: 1200 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:9b41 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.7 driver: i915 compositor: gnome-shell 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics (Comet Lake 3x8 GT2) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 19.3.5 compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:02c8 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.5.8-1-MANJARO 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9462 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 3000 
  bus ID: 00:14.3 chip ID: 8086:02f0 
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: br-3c04500043ca state: down mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-2: br-63c8ac713143 state: down mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-3: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 60.41 GiB (12.7%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB512HBJQ-000L2 
  size: 476.94 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> rev: 3L1QEXF7 
  scheme: GPT 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 97.93 GiB used: 32.53 GiB (33.2%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7 
  ID-2: /home size: 125.14 GiB used: 26.99 GiB (21.6%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p8 
  ID-3: swap-1 size: 16.00 GiB used: 921.3 MiB (5.6%) fs: swap 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 40.0 C mobo: 37.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 314 Uptime: 3d 23h 09m Memory: 15.36 GiB used: 7.14 GiB (46.5%) 
  Init: systemd v: 244 Compilers: gcc: 9.2.1 clang: 9.0.1 Shell: bash 
  v: 5.0.16 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.37
```

There are all the appropriate drivers installed, and reinstalled as per multiple online guides and forums, including the Arch Wiki.

I am at an utter loss of what to do now, and am looking for any ideas or pointers as to what to do next, or where to go to report this.

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Just a hunch try: `sudo --group aa-notify aa-notify -p` Do you get any notifications when it is not working?

Comment: Notifications are still working fine. I managed to get it working by switching to Wayland, although I'm not sure if this a permanent fix or now.

Comment: I did not say, "check if notifications are working". I said "try: `sudo --group aa-notify aa-notify -p` Do you get any notifications when it is not working?" -- That command may cause a notification when the problem happens (and it may not).

Comment: When I run `sudo --group aa-notify aa-notify -p` I get `sudo: unknown group: aa-notify`. If I run it with just `sudo aa-notify -p`, I get `Cannot read '/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Yes sorry I have added that group, and given it read permission on that file. Does the file exist for you? Is apparmor active? If you don't have apparmor active, then my hunch is wrong. I can't remember how you would check to see if it is active.